# Linq left not in right table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm not much of a LINQ programmer so this is baffling me somewhat. I have two tables: first a Schedule with a StartDate and an EndDate, plus ID; secondly, a ScheduleInstance table with an InstanceDate and a ScheduleID. For every day between Schedule.StartDate and Schedule.EndDate inclusive I need to create a ScheduleInstance row - however, only 24 hours ahead. As schedules are created and deleted within the 24 hour look-ahead, I have to spawn a checker every n minutes to check whether the ScheduleInstance for the ScheduleID exists within that 24 hour window.

Models:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
public class ScheduleInstance
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public DateTime InstanceDate { get; set; }
}
```

The start of the LINQ:

```
var skeds = from sked in context.Schedules
            join instance in context.ScheduleInstances
                on sked.ID equals instance.ScheduleID
            where ((sked.StartDate <= DateTime.Now) && (sked.EndDate >= DateTime.Now))
            select sked.ID;
```

(obviously wrong)

To summarise, I need to get a list of Schedule.ID where a ScheduleInstance does NOT exist for ScheduleInstance.InstanceDate within the next 24 hours.

Many thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

```
        DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        var skeds = from sked in context.Schedules
                    join instance in context.ScheduleInstances
                         on sked.ID equals instance.ScheduleID into g
                    where (sked.StartDate <= tomorrow) &&
                          (sked.EndDate >= tomorrow) &&
                           !g.Any()
                    select sked;
```

This now works in that an instance is created (in subsequent code that's not relevant here) if one doesn't exist for tomorrow. If I set StartDate to Now+2mins then after 2 minutes that Schedule gets created - perfect. However, if I advance the clock 24 hours, I should be getting a whole bunch of new instances. To reiterate, if a Schedule start date is now and the end date is 30 days later, then I should end up with 31 instances, with each new instance created 24 hours in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the one hand I should have adopted the KISS principle. On the other hand I have three queries instead of one. But it works!

```
        var instances = from inst in context.ScheduleInstances
                        where (inst.StartDateTime >= DateTime.Now)
                        && (inst.StartDateTime < tomorrow)
                        select inst;

        var skeds = from sked in context.Schedules
                    where (sked.StartDate <= DateTime.Now)
                    && (sked.EndDate >= tomorrow)
                    select sked;

        var none = from sked in skeds
                   join inst in instances
                   on sked.ID equals inst.ScheduleID
                   into tg
                   from tcheck in tg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where tcheck == null
                   select sked;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the trick

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
var nextDay = today.AddDays(1);
var scheds = from sched in context.Schedules                        
             join instance in context.ScheduleInstances
                on sched.ID equals instance.ScheduleID into schedInstances
             where (sched.StartDate >= today) && 
                   (sched.EndDate <= nextDay) &&
                   !schedInstances.Any()
             select sched.ID;
```

Comment: This seems to be on the right lines - thanks. It doesn't like the Now.AddDays so I pulled that out of the query and had a local variable equivalent. Also, the StartDate and EndDate <=/=> are the wrong way around. However, only one instance seems to be created because there is no filter on that. I'll post updated code in my original question.

Comment: @GeoffM sure, moving nextDay variable to the locals is a good decision. But >= and <= should work. As I understand the question, you need to check only schedules within next 24 hours

Comment: Thanks for the update. The >= / <= won't work because the StartDate could be a month ago and the EndDate in six months, for example. The idea is to create a new Instance record for every day between Start and End, but only one day ahead. So, in that example, as of today I should have about 30 records since StartDate, and in six months' time there should be another 6x30 records roughly.

Comment: What I need to do is pick ScheduleInstances falling on tomorrow's date, however I can't put it into the "join" clause (even using new {} as it says types are incompatible (the field definitions are identical, as confirmed by checking in Database Explorer)) nor the "where" (out of context).

Answer (score 1):

So you want the schedules that have less than one instance a day between the schedule's StartDate and tomorrow?  Here is a rough idea of how to accomplish that:

```
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
var skeds = from sked in context.Schedules
            join instance in context.ScheduleInstances
                 on sked.ID equals instance.ScheduleID into g
            let instances = g.Where(x => x.InstanceDate >= sked.StartDate &&
                                         x.InstanceDate <= tomorrow)
            where (sked.StartDate <= tomorrow) &&
                  (sked.EndDate >= tomorrow) &&
                  (instances.Count() < (tomorrow - sked.StartDate).Days)
            select sked;
```

Comment: "DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.". I can't work out where it's having a problem though!

Comment: Problem seems to be the (tomorrow - sked.StartDate).Days section. I'm trying to think of a solution. Incidentally if I replace that with 1 then tomorrow's instances get created but (advancing the system clock 24 hours) not the next day.

Comment: Thanks - it was helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (untested)

```
var skeds = from sked in context.Schedules
            from instance in context.ScheduleInstances
            where (sked.ID == instance.ScheduleID) && ((sked.StartDate <= DateTime.Now) && sked.EndDate >= DateTime.Now))
            select sked.ID;
```

Comment: I think this will only return schedule IDs for instances that *do* exist, rather those that *don't*.